# swift - object changes after function call

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobject

[image]
[image]

I have an object using the below code

```
    name = "Toma"
    let toma = setupPet(name, family: "Hawn", stage: 1, imageName: "hawn_toma", imageNamef: "", imageNameEgg: "hawn_egg", hatchEXP: 5000, desc: "", eggDesc: "", rarity: "Common")
    
    name = "Hawn"
    let hawn = setupPet(name, family: "Hawn", stage: 2, imageName: "hawn", imageNamef: "", imageNameEgg: "hawn_egg", hatchEXP: 5000, desc: "", eggDesc: "", rarity: "Common")
    hawn.basePet = toma
    
    let tomaToHawn = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Evolution", inManagedObjectContext: self.appData.moc) as! Evolution
    tomaToHawn.evolveTo = hawn
    tomaToHawn.howEvolve = "Level"
    tomaToHawn.evolveValue = "10"
    
    NSLog("\(tomaToHawn.evolveTo!.name)")
    
    toma.addEvolveToObject(tomaToHawn)
    
    NSLog("\(tomaToHawn.evolveTo!.name)")
```

Now the result of the two NSLogs gives different values,

> Optional("Hawn")
>
> Optional("Toma")

So it changed after the addEvolveToObject call
The method consists of

```
class Pet: NSManagedObject {

    func addEvolveToObject(value:Evolution) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("evolveTo");
        items.addObject(value)
    }
    
}
```

I've also tried the add evolve using  @NSManaged func but get the same result. After the object is added to the nsset, the evolveto is being set to the pet its being added to. Other fields keep the correct data

Edit
I've narrowed the issue down to the addEvolveToObject method. If i print using NSLog("Pet CD: (value.evolveTo?.name)") before the items.addobject call it gives the correct value, but if i print the same after the statement, it gives a different value

IE:

```
func addEvolveToObject(value:Evolution) {
    NSLog("********************************************************************")
    let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("evolveTo");
    NSLog("Pet CD: \(value.evolveTo?.name)")
    items.addObject(value)
    NSLog("Pet CD: \(value.evolveTo?.name)")
    NSLog("********************************************************************")
}
```

gives

> Pet CD: Optional("Mel")
>
> Pet CD: Optional("Joan")

If i comment out the add object line both NSLogs give the correct result

Class Codes:
setup - just sets up the database
import UIKit
import CoreData

```
class Setup: NSObject {
    
    let appData : AppData = AppData.sharedInstance
    
    func setup() {
            // Hawn
        name = "Toma"
        let toma = setupPet(name, family: "Hawn", stage: 1, imageName: "hawn_toma", imageNamef: "", imageNameEgg: "hawn_egg", hatchEXP: 5000, desc: "", eggDesc: "", rarity: "Common")
        
        name = "Hawn"
        let hawn = setupPet(name, family: "Hawn", stage: 2, imageName: "hawn", imageNamef: "", imageNameEgg: "hawn_egg", hatchEXP: 5000, desc: "", eggDesc: "", rarity: "Common")
        hawn.basePet = toma
        
        let tomaToHawn = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Evolution", inManagedObjectContext: self.appData.moc) as! Evolution
        tomaToHawn.evolveTo = hawn
        tomaToHawn.howEvolve = "Level"
        tomaToHawn.evolveValue = "10"
        
        toma.addEvolveToObject(tomaToHawn)

        appData.saveContext()
    }
    func setupPet(name : String, family : String, stage : NSNumber, imageName : String, imageNamef : String, imageNameEgg : String, hatchEXP : NSNumber, desc : String, eggDesc : String, rarity : String) -> Pet {
        
        let pet : Pet = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Pet",inManagedObjectContext: appData.moc) as! Pet
        pet.name = name
        pet.family = family
        pet.stage = stage
        pet.imageName = imageName
        pet.imageNamef = imageNamef
        pet.imageNameEgg = imageNameEgg
        pet.hatchEXP = hatchEXP
        pet.rarity = rarity
        pet.desc = desc
        pet.eggDesc = eggDesc
        
        return pet
    }
}
```

Pet - core data properties class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Pet {

    @NSManaged var desc: String?
    @NSManaged var eggDesc: String?
    @NSManaged var family: String?
    @NSManaged var gained: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var hatchEXP: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var imageName: String?
    @NSManaged var imageNameEgg: String?
    @NSManaged var imageNamef: String?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var rarity: String?
    @NSManaged var stage: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var adopt: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var evolveTo: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var userPets: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var basePet: Pet?

}
```

Pet

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class Pet: NSManagedObject {

    func addEvolveToObject(value:Evolution) {
        let items = mutableSetValueForKey("evolveTo") as NSMutableSet;
        items.addObject(value)
    }
    
}
```

And the evolution core data class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Evolution {

    @NSManaged var evolveValue: String?
    @NSManaged var howEvolve: String?
    @NSManaged var evolveTo: Pet?

}
```

The pet class can take multiple evolution objects, each evolution object is for one pet

Comment: No, i'm trying to work out why the object changes when i've not told it to

Comment: I've also tried the add evolve using @NSManaged func but get the same result. After the object is added to the nsset, the evolveto is being set to the pet its being added to. Other fields keep the correct data

Comment: How are your relationships and inverses setup?

Comment: Have added images showing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is bi-directional relationships. When you connect one end of the relationship the other end will be connected for you, so when you add something to the set (the many end) the other property (the one end) will get set for you. This is what you're seeing.

If this isn't what you want then you need to add 2 more relationships, because you do want all relationships to be bi-directional but you also want to separate the 2 that you currently have.

Comment: What would o go about setting the values for the extra relationships to?#

Comment: you wouldn't, it would happen automatically, your code would stay the same you'd just add 2 new relationships and connect them as the new inverses (hope that makes sense) - so it isn't a new relationship, it's two new ends for your existing 2 relationship ends

Comment: Lets see if i understand. i create two new relationships and assign them to the inverse of the existing ones? Is that one relationship on each entity?

Comment: yeah, so `evolveTo` <-> `evolutions`, and I'd change the name of `evolveTo` on `Pet` as it doesn't represent the multiplicity, but something like `evolveTos` <-> `evolution`

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a go in a bit when i have access to my mac. I have actually changed the relationship names, just in case that had something to do with it, having both named the same, i know it was unlikely but i was trying anything that i thought of

Comment: ok, that seems to be working, other than giving me warning about inversion relationships should be set

Comment: Each should have an inverse for sure